# IFrame PDF - Remove internal PDF (grey) border around and between pages

Tags: html, css, pdf, iframe, pdf-viewer

I am using a simple iframe-tag to display the PDF viewer in chrome.

[Remove grey border in PDF viewer - iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOQJO.png)

Does anybody know if it is possible to remove the grey border ("Border in iframe") or how I can resolve this issue ?

I have tried:
frameborder is deprecated. - Not working
style = "border: "none"" - Not working
#view=Fit&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0 - Not working

Demo of my issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dheeraj-iframe-pdf